# Cross domain posting to normal aspx page with jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cross-domain

I have a requirement where I have to post a xml data in form post method to a cross domain page using jquery where there is no web-service written its normal aspx page. I am using the following code also google a couple of hours but find no  luck please help me out to overcome with this situation.

```
 $.ajax({ 
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://test-dev.test.net/default.aspx",
                        data: "{'a_sScoringType':'" + $("input[id$='hdnEvalSystem']").val() + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (json) {

                        alert(json);

                        }});
```

Comment: Are you using web Method in default.aspx?                                    did you try crossDomain property?

Comment: no there is no webmethod and I cannot create it because its not under my control.

Comment: can you give some details about default.aspx code?

Comment: That is out side my domain they have just given me a retrun url where i have to post value using javascript or jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Read it may be it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross-domain requests. There's more information on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/522297). As long as your web page is written to handle incoming data, you should be able to send data to it from your current domain.